# Timestamp field from firestore showing an invalid date if the field does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

These are my codes. `selectedDate` is a timestamp field:

```
<ListItemText
                          primary={
                            new Date(
                              user.items?.selectedDate?.seconds * 1000
                            ).toDateString() +
                            " at " +
                            new Date(
                              user.items?.selectedDate?.seconds * 1000
                            ).toLocaleTimeString()
                          }
                    />
```

It does show the data correctly. However, if the `selectedDate` does exist, it will show:

> Invalid date at Invalid date

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should write some code to check for the condition where that data is not available and decide what you want to show instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug commented, you'll want to check whether the document has a `` field, before trying to convert its value to a date. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<ListItemText
  primary={user.items?.selectedDate ? (
    new Date(
      user.items?.selectedDate?.seconds * 1000
    ).toDateString() +
    " at " +
    new Date(
      user.items?.selectedDate?.seconds * 1000
    ).toLocaleTimeString()
  ) : "No date" }
/>
```